# RPi B v2.0 P5 header on RPi B+

Tags: gpio

I have the PiFi DAC v1.0 from VullersTech that requires the P5 header which only seems to be available on the RPi B v2.0 ("Made in the UK"). Are the P5 header pins somehow accessible on the RPi B+, so I can use the PiFi on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Similar functionality exists (as @joan mentions), but the physical pins do not appear, so the software would need to be changed.

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=91046&p=636782#p636782

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the PiFi DAC needs.

P5 has gpios 28-31 which could be configured in alternate modes as I2C (28=SDA, 29=SCL) or PCM (28=CLK, 29=FS, 30=DIN, 31=DOUT).

The I2C functions may now be available from gpios 0-1 on the B+.
The PCM functions may now be available from gpio 18-21 on the B+.